# Can I use groupByKey in each partition of RDD? or how can I find the largest key of each partition?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I want to find the largest key (also the last key) in each partition, and there may be two or there largest keys (equal with each other) in each partition.

```
DStream.map(lambda x: (x,1)).transform(lambda rdd: rdd
.mapPartitions(lambda x: groupByKey(x))).pprint()
```

and spark tells me:

```
NameError: global name 'groupByKey' is not defined
```

So, I try to write a function by myself, and I found that the entity I get from `map partitions()` is a Python iterator. It is hard for to get the last two or there items directly.

Could someone tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What ever function you provide, that would be executed at partition level on each executor. So you can have your largest key logic in that method and store the result in a broadcast variable of type array, as you might have multiple values for each partition.You can refer the theory [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shared-variables)

Comment: Sorry I still confused. Do you mean I should use a fixed number as the value of broadcast?  I know 'broadcast' can send a value to all partitions, but the largest key in each partition is different, I feel that sending a same number to each partition cannot work.

Comment: Sorry the broadcast variables are to send read only data from driver to executors. Your requirement is to get from executor. You can get the max and just sent it to output. Since output is written per partition, each value will have its max in the partitioned data.

Comment: Thank you. Then how can I do that ? I am not able to use 'groupByKey' or 'reduceByKey' in each partition... So I need to write a function by myself ?